# Why is `OR`bit operation is used when initializing a variable in embedded programming?

Tags: c, embedded, bare-metal

This information is coming from an embedding programming tutorial from YOUTUBE.

The instructor recommends to assign a value to a certain memory location by using an `OR` operation.

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    |=   (1U<<5);
```

My question is why not just,

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    =   (1U<<5);
```

The definition of SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    is

```
#define SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400FE608))
```

Given that the value at the memory location of SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R  is 0,
I understand that both assignments are equal.

But wouldn't first assignment cause unnecessary bit operation?

Is there a special reason for utilizing `OR` bitwise operation when writing a value to specific memory location?

Comment: That's one of the problems learning C and embedded programming by youtube. A good book will give you the whole picture, not half-baked snapshots without proper didactics.

Comment: Because when working with hardware, each bit is meaning some *operation/setting*. So once you are triggering one operation by setting a specific bit, you usually don't want to affect the other bits.

Comment: Using OR will set the flag without touching the other flags. Without it, only the set flag witll have a value of 1.

Comment: First of all it's not used to initialize SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R, second SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R is not a variable.

Comment: @user3528438 - Yup.  It is not a variable.  It is dereferencing a memory location.  So instead of the word `initialize`, would `writing` to the memory be the right way of saying it?

Comment: No, it's clearly a in-place updating or a read-update-write operation.

Comment: @user3528438 - This was supposed to be an interrupt safe atomic operation, improving from interrupt unsafe  RMW(read-modify-write) operation to  just W(write) operation.

Comment: Atomic how? Does your compiler AND processor guarantee this be atomic? Otherwise no it doesn't improve atomicity.

Comment: Short answer: `|=` can be used to set one or several bits. `=` is used for setting the whole byte.

Comment: Regarding atomic access, it entirely depends on which assembler code this boils down to. Compound vs simple assignment tend to be inconsistent in which one that generates a bit set and which one that generates a read-modify-write. If this matters, then always disassemble such code, or better yet, write it in inline assembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the tutorial suggests that you use an `OR` instruction instead of a direct assignment is because the target value may be different from zero due to circumstances that are beyond your control, and you do not want to modify any bits other than bit 6.

Answer (score 2):

`SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    |=   (1U<<5);`

is equivalent to:

`SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    |   (1U<<5);`

where `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you know that the register resets to zero and/or for other reasons you know the register is zero, then the read-modify-write is excess overhead.  You are correct.

So one school of thought is, dont know how things works and just blast data without regard for what was there.  Bad.

Another is as part of a section of init code, perform the reset of that block, put the block in a known state, then you can assume/know the values for those registers and do writes rather than read-modify-writes.

Another is to assume this code is the first thing run on that peripheral and you can do writes instead of read-modify-writes because you know the post reset state of these registers.

Eventually you get to the school of thought is make fewer assumptions and only change the bits I want to change and ideally leave the rest untouched, so read-modify-writes.  Even to the pain of want to make PA3 an output so read-modify-write a direction register to change one bit, then want to make PA4 an output, so read-modify-write the register to change the next bit over, could have done that in one read-modify-write, but through library layering and such.

The easiest init is to force or otherwise know that you are post reset and init based on what you know about reset, you might not use interrupts for a peripheral so you dont touch the interrupt enable register or clear interrupt register.  And it all works great.  if/when you get that working and if you for some reason need to now have something that can change hot, you need to change the init to touch all the registers, and in some cases that means writes without read-modify-writes, so we are back to that question.

Yes, you are correct if you know the register was zero before, the read-modify-write is excess code and not necessary, it is wasteful.  But, as a habit it is good to only mess with the bits you are using (control bits for gpio only mess with the one gpio pin you are setting up, dont mess up the others) through read-modify-writes.  Very rare occasions there may be a bit that is undocumented that if you write the wrong way will make the thing not work, usually the documentation will have some extra text on that one saying it is reserved and dont change it (where other bits in other registers might say reserved, should be zero).

Comment: Note the re-init hot without a reset approach (and not knowing/assuming the prior state) is the same as the blast through without regard for what is there, but do it in the right order, and hit all the registers, makes it okay rather than bad.

Answer (score 1):

An OR is **not** the same as an assignment.  With and OR, only the bits set in the mask are set in the destination, leaving the others unchanged.  With an assignment, *all* bits are set to the value of the mask.

Consider the following:

```
unsigned x = 0, y = 0;
x = (1<<5);
y = (1<<5);
printf("x=%x, y=%x\n", x, y);

x = 0x00;
y = 0x80;
x |= (1<<5);
y |= (1<<5);
printf("x=%x, y=%x\n", x, y);
```

Output:

```
x=20, y=20
x=20, y=a0
```

As you can see from this example, if the source value is 0 then the result is equivalent.  But if it is non-zero, they are not.

In general, if you're setting a bit you should use a logical OR, even if the source value is 0.  Then you'll be safe just in case it's not for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
(1U<<5) = 00100000
A |= B is equal to A = A | B
```

When you do

```
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R    =   (1U<<5);
```

you are adjusting ALL the bits of the variable, and setting it to 00100000

with the OR operation, you set only the target bit (5th) as:

```
previous: xxXxxxxx OR
(1<<5):   00100000 = 
Result:   xx1xxxxx
```

in similar way:

```
previous: xxXxxxxx AND
~(1<<5):  11011111 = 
Result:   xx0xxxxx
```

is used to clear a single bit in a register

Comment: I gave UV but the examples only shift **1** by **4** bits.

Comment: Ops, you are right @WeatherVane, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, the value may not be zero or they may change (especially as it's registers you speak of) in which case you'd need to perform a read-modify-write in order to preserve the original values of other bits. This will most likely be broken down into three separate assembly instructions, even though you may make it a "one-liner" in C/C++. Having said that, if you happen to be pre-empted in between those instructions (when you use RTOS) or there happens to be an interrupt and the value of the register changes before you get back to the "write" step, you will overwrite the bits that changed in between.

Now that you speak of embedded programming and registers, this may have some very nasty consequences, as simply writing 0s or 1s to a register may trigger some hardware action. This can be very time consuming for you to track down.

Answer (score 1):

The register will likely have a hardware defined reset value (which may or may not be zero); at *assignment* previous code, or the reset itself may well have modified or set other bits in the register that this assignment should not modify.  It is what is known as a read-modify-write operation.